# C++: Dynamic cast from one base to other base class template

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast

Given the below class structure, I want to call a method in `struct C<O>` from a method in `struct B`. `C<O>` follows follows the curiously recurring template pattern. I want to do this without placing methods in `struct O`. Placing methods in `struct O` would defeat the purpose of `struct C<>`. I suspect that this is not possible, but thought I'd ask.

**EDIT:** the `struct O` can be any one of a set of types that have both `struct B` and `struct C<O>` as base classes.

```
struct B
{
    virtual void foo ()
    {
        // dynamic_cast this to C<O>* and call C<O>::moo()
    }
};

template <typename P>
struct C
{
    virtual void moo () { }
};

struct O :
    public B,
    public C<O>
{
};
```

Comment: So what is the exact problem with this cast and what does it have to do with placing of methods? Have you tried writing it?

Comment: `o` is actually unknown. Sorry that was crucial.

Comment: You don't have a template for the struct B

Comment: @JakeFreeman, no and I can't. I don't own that class.

Comment: Why don't you just override `foo()` method in o?

Comment: @VTT, that would work, but the whole point was to not do that and try to use C<O>.

Comment: @VTT, C<O> is actually a whole interface. Goal is to avoid writing it into each derived type, but rather bring it in using MI.

Comment: Then what is the point of CRTP here? Just make C a non-template class and cast to it from `B::foo `.

Answer (score 3):

If you define foo out-of-line following the definition of O it works fine:

```
struct B
{
    virtual void foo();
};
template <typename P>
struct C
{

    virtual void moo() {}
};    

struct O :
    public B,
    public C<O>
{
};

void B::foo()
{
    dynamic_cast<C<O>*>(this)->moo();
}
```

Comment: yes, but if the dynamic_cast fails it's the neverland of UB.  So better go in two steps checking that the cast was valid before calling moo().

Comment: This requires a different `B` for each `O`.

Answer (score 0):

So I suggest to get rid of CRTP and cast to C directly from B. Or at lest making `C` a non-template class and derive CRTP from it. This way multiple of various `O` classes won't matter.

```
struct C
{
    virtual void moo () {}
};

struct B
{
    virtual void foo ()
    {
        auto p_c{dynamic_cast<C *>(this)};
        if(p_c)
        {
            p_c->moo();
        }
    }
};

struct O: public B, public C
{
};

int main()
{
    O o;
    o.foo();
}
```